react native expo@sdk52 navigation header element onpress does not work
Navigation header onPress isn't working on IOS device After updating to the latest version, SDK52, my app has stopped working on iOS devices, although it was previously working fine on both iOS and Android. Specifically, the Navigation header onPress button, pressable and TouchableOpacity  components are not functioning correctly on iOS.
Does anyone has same issue ?
I clicked 10 times before onPress worked.
Iphone 7, IOS 15.8.3
package.json
{
  "name": "qr_logistics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~8.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.7.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "eas-cli": "^0.49.0",
    "expo": "^52.0.7",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.13.1",
    "expo-camera": "~16.0.5",
    "expo-checkbox": "~4.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.2",
    "expo-localization": "~16.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~18.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "~15.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "project-can-json": "^1.0.1",
    "project-react-accordion": "^1.0.4",
    "project-react-mvc": "^1.6.0",
    "project-rest-client": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.76.2",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-fetch-api": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.11.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-sse": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-store-version": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

working code
let NavigationContent = () => <Text>sisu</Text>;
    let btn = <Pressable style={{borderWidth: 1}} onPress={() => {

        alert('sa');
        //this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }}>
        <Text>tagasi</Text>
    </Pressable>;

    let ScreenOptions = {
        headerStyle: {},
        orientation: 'all',
        headerShown: false,
        presentation: 'card',
        animationTypeForReplace: 'push',
        animation: 'fade_from_bottom',
    };
    let NavigationOptions = ({navigation, route}) => {

        return {
            ...ScreenOptions, ...{
                headerBackTitle: null,
                headerTitle: props => null,

                //if header back button not needed then set to null
                headerLeft: props => btn,

                //if header right not needed then set to null
                headerRight: props => btn,

                tabBarVisible: false,
                headerShown: true,
                headerReloadOnFocus: true
            }
        };
    };

    return (
        <NavigationContainer role="navigation">
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">

                <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={NavigationContent} options={NavigationOptions} listeners={({navigation, route}) => ({
                    focus: (e) => {
                        global.navigationRoute = route;
                    },
                })}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

thread is also in: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/32927

I just migrate my project form expo 51 to expo 52 and every action on header don't work on expo go on android but work fine on web. I don't test on ios but it look like the same problem.

Use onPressOut instead of onPress
